# Can my friend use their Rockstar account for GTA V while logged in to my Epic Games account?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I am logging in to my Epic Games account on my friends PC so they can download GTA V, which is in my library.

When it has finished downloading, can my friend then log in with his Rockstar account and play, or will he have to use my Rockstar account to play GTA V too?

Comment: *[Comments Removed]* - The discussion here wasn't relevant to the question and was getting out of hand - please - to *all* parties involved, take a moment to cool off and remember the [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct). If you want to (civilly) discuss the legalities surrounding the enforcement of a TOS, please do so in [chat], or if you wish to make a point that something should be on or off topic, please raise a discussion on [meta]. In the meantime I have edited out the point of contention which wasn't even really relevant to the question anyway.